# View Reloads When Frame is Changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `YouTubePlayer` (from [here](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player)) in my app. I have a `UIViewController` (we'll call this `MainViewController`) with a `UITableView` full of videos. Whenever a user taps on a cell, it opens another `UIViewController` (we'll call this `DetailViewController`) with my custom xib view called `playerView`. Like I said, `playerView` is a custom xib view and in that view is my `YouTubePlayer`. This is how I set up playerView in my `DetailViewController`

```
playerContainer.addSubview(playerView)
playerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerContainer.frame.size.width , height: playerContainer.frame.size.height)
playerView.player.loadVideoID(nowPlayingVideo.id)
```

Ok so this works great. BUT... whenever the user dismisses `DetailViewController`, I want `playerView` to be moved to the `MainViewController`. Like where the user can see what is playing in the background. So to do this, I added this code in `DetailViewController`...

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    nowPlayingView.addSubview(playerView)
    playerView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: width, height: height)
    playerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

`nowPlayingView` is another custom xib view and is added to the app's window earlier on. So this is where I start running into problems. This code works great. The frame is changed correctly and it's added to nowPlayingView, but, the `YouTubePlayer` in `playerView` seems to reload. So it pauses playback, shows a loading icon, and then resumes. It's pretty annoying. This shouldn't be happening because the video is already loaded in the `YouTubePlayer`. I'm pretty sure it happens only whenver I am changing the frame of `playerView`. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When the video resumes playing after loading, does the video start over or does it resume where it left off before changing the view?

Comment: It resumes about where it was left off. Sometimes maybe like a second or so before

Comment: Hmmm. The only thing I can think is happening is that the video is saved, then a few seconds later when the view disappears, it’s brought back up and is delayed due to the time it takes to close the window. Now this isn’t good for processing, but try adding the view when the video is first loaded, so it’s playing on the view controller in the background. So the mainView And the video view are playing simultaneously. If the loading is fixed, try to do some managing code with the video. This is all assuming that your view with the video is a module though.

Comment: And if it works, then we know that it’s because the time in which the video is saved is delayed by the time it takes to close the window. Hopefully that provides a better understanding more options when trying to efficiently solve this. let me know if you find a solution because I will also be working on a video app with the same feature soon!